# Sybase ASE: Why "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table" takes many minutes

Tags: sql, performance, sap-ase

We have in a Sybase ASE 16.0 on SuSE Linux a growing table with ~18 million rows which has two indices:

```
create INDEX ind_ig_bigstrings on ig_bigstrings(id,seq_id)
create INDEX ig_bigstrings_syb_id_col on ig_bigstrings( SYB_IDENTITY_COL )
```

A `select count(*) from ig_bigstrings` takes ~5 minutes and a second run takes only 3 seconds. The plan shows that the index is used:

```
1> select count(*) from ig_bigstrings
2> go

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).
Optimized using Serial Mode


    STEP 1
        The type of query is SELECT.

    2 operator(s) under root

       |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 2)
       |
       |   |SCALAR AGGREGATE Operator (VA = 1)
       |   |  Evaluate Ungrouped COUNT AGGREGATE.
       |   |
       |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
       |   |   |  FROM TABLE
       |   |   |  ig_bigstrings
       |   |   |  Index : ind_ig_bigstrings
       |   |   |  Forward Scan.
       |   |   |  Positioning at index start.
       |   |   |  Index contains all needed columns. Base table will not be read.
       |   |   |  Using I/O Size 4 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
       |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.


             
 ----------- 
    18917916
```

Why a scan through the index does take so long?

Btw: I loaded the same table into a PostgreSQL 13.1 server and the operation takes only 15 seconds when the index does not exist and 2 seconds after creating an index.

Comment: first guess: first query had to pull index from disk and disk read times are (relatively) slow on this machine; second guess: first query was blocked by another process holding an exclusive lock on the desired index; hard to say without monitoring data (eg, MDA tables, sp_lock, sp_who, etc)

Answer (score 2):

In general this could be due to several reasons (not an exhaustive list):

1. The table or its indices may be very fragmented, which would result in its (derived) statistics being very low.
2. I/O contention on the disk devices or slow disk I/O in general.
3. A default data cache of insufficient size to handle the amount of data.
4. A large I/O pool that is missing or of insufficient size, resulting in the query optimizer opting for the regular I/O pool instead.
5. A lot of forwarded rows in the table.

Looking at the query plan, scenario 1 seems rather unlikely, since that would result in a table scan being preferred over an index walk by the query optimizer. Use the 'update statistics' statement
to update the table and/or index statistics or use `'reorg rebuild'` or `'drop index'` and `'create index'` to improve the derived statistics.

I/O contention or slow disk I/O would also be felt by other processes on the system, so that may be a thing to look at.

Ordinarily one or more table rows will fit nicely into a single page. However since there is often room for a non-integer number of rows in a single
page, Sybase ASE will attempt to fit as much of these rows in a single page. Whatever does not fit is written to a separate page, for a which
a reference is placed on the original page. This is called a forwarded row and a lot of them are detrimental to performance. If the table was
created quite recently and/or the content has not changed much since, the number of forwarded rows will be quite small. However, if there were
a lot of inserts, deletes or updates to the table, this number will have grown steadily over time. Use `'reorg forwarded rows'` to improve this.

However, the most likely cause to me is either scenario 3 or 4, or a combination of those two. Especially since the query plan tells us it is
using a I/O size of 4 Kbytes. The page size of the large I/O pool is often 8 times the physical page size (the page size used for the
installation of Sybase ASE). For a 2K (the minimum) page size, this would be 16K, for an 8K page size this would be 64K and so on. From the
query plan text I reckon a 4K page size is used for this server. Use:
`sp_cacheconfig "<cache name>", "<size>"` to setup a new data cache or
grow the data cache (there is always a 'default data cache', which is usually a good candidate for this). Next setup or grow a large I/O pool
in this data cache by running `sp_poolconfig "<cache name>", "<size>", "<page size>"`. In the above case I would use a large I/O page size of 32K.